# What is good variable type for full text search in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, freetext

I am declaring a new stored procedure in MS SQL Server for implementing Full Text Search and my query is some thing like this:

```
Select * from table WHERE FREETEXT((col1, col2), @Search_Statement)
```

The question has exactly written bellow:

What is the proper data type for @Search_Statement variable to support most of searches and also have the best performance?

(I know that if I make @Search_Statement variable long it supports more search queries but executing queries with longer @Search_Statement may affect performance and google limit search queries to 32 words: https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/1176637-216124982)

I don't know which of these datatypes to use for @Search_Statement in my stored procedure: Nvarchar(100), Nvarchar(500) or Nvarchar(MAX)
Which would be the best choice? (Performance, and all other aspects)

**Update**: I know I should use nvarchar but what is proper size of nvarchar? nvarchar(100),(200),(500),... or even nvarchar(MAX)?

Comment: The best variable data type will be the data type of the column you are searching on, sql server will not have to do implicit conversions hence you may get better performance. char/varchar/[Data Size] all must match the type of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [FREETEXT Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx)

> FREETEXT ( { column_name | (column_list) | * } 
>             , 'freetext_string' [ , LANGUAGE language_term ] )
>
> freetext_string is **nvarchar**. An implicit conversion occurs when another character data type is used as input. In the following example, the @SearchWord variable, which is defined as varchar(30), causes an implicit conversion in the FREETEXT predicate.

Comment: Thanks but what is proper nvarchar(size) for the nvarchar variable?

Comment: Also relevant from that link: `Because "parameter sniffing" does not work across conversion, use nvarchar for better performance.`

Comment: @MohammadHa nvarchar(8000) is the largest size allowed for the freetext string. nvarchar(max) is not allowed. I doubt the size affects the performance of the query -- the *contents* of the freetext string will have a much greater impact.

Comment: @Keith Actually, `nvarchar(4000)` is the largest allowed "non-max" `nvarchar`, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql). The `varchar(8000)` is possible though.